# Ways to get around the restriction of only once creation of recovery disks?

Tags: windows-7

On my Lenovo T400 with Windows 7, I am allowed only one time to create a set of recovery disks from the recovery partition. So I was wondering if there are some ways to get around this restriction, because some of the disks may be accidentally missing or damaged, or I might just need multiple copies for multiple places? Thanks!

Comment: Smells like you want to circumvent DRM/EULA, which is Off-Topic on SU. What hinders you to create a recovery disk? What hinders you to ask your vendor for another one?

Comment: From previous posts he's not necessarily sure the first attempt worked.

Comment: @Bobby, I don't think it has anything to do with DRM/EULA circumvention. In fact, the Windows 7 EULA for pre-installed OS (available from http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx) images specifically permits making a backup copy, see section 10.

Comment: @Bobby: I don't know what you are implying. It has been quite a while since the laptop was purchased, and it could be out of warranty when bad things happen to the recovery disks.

Comment: @Tim - If it's out of warranty/not covered (say, you lose them) you just buy another set.  $45 from Lenovo.  EDIT: I'd add that I'm curious why you're so paranoid about this...

Comment: @Rob: Yes: `You may make one backup copy of the software.` As far as I understand this, this permits to make exactly one copy...not multiple. Now the question is if the Recovery System does permit to make multiple copies...but @Tim was implying that this is not the case: `I am allowed only one time to...I might just need multiple copies...` Therefor my request for clarification on that.

Comment: @Bobby, the recovery disks aren't a copy, they're the original. Given that creating them irrevocably removes the ability to create them again. It's basically the OEM being cheap and saying "you can have a recovery DVD, if you burn it yourself". Making a copy of *that* for backup purposes is permitted under the EULA. Either way, EULAs are leaky as a sieve and the OPs intent is quite clearly not malicious, so us continuing to nit-pick over DRM/EULA issues is utterly pointless =)

Comment: @Bobby: I meant when taking my laptop to different places, for example, office, home, and some other places I frequently travel to.... I hope I don't need to carry the same set of disks around all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no different to only having one copy of a Windows installation DVD (the fact that you get one x86 and one x64 DVD non-withstanding), but there's nothing stopping you making a copy of that DVD. Therefore, there's nothing stopping you from making a copy of the recovery disks that the Lenovo recovery partition provides.

Anything else will probably require instructions that are specific to any custom recovery disk software that Lenovo use.

**Update**: (because of the EULA/DRM circumvention point raised in comments) [IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL), but based on the license document for Windows 7 which is available after filling in the [form at microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx), you are within your rights under it to make a copy of the recovery disks.

Comment: Thanks! How do you recommend to make a copy? Simply copy, or make some iso files, or something else? And store to another storage device.

Comment: Tim, use your DVD copying software of choice, Nero, or whatever you have available =)

Answer (score 1):

I think probably best you speak to the manufacturer/seller. You will most likely have already agreed to this restriction in accepting a license.